# Скачивание с правами

Tags: php

Мне нужно сделать так, чтобы можно было скачать файл только тому, кто правильно ввёл логин и пароль (https://my.website/download.php?login=admin&password=admin), а в другом случае, просто ничего не делать.

Возможно ли это сделать? Возможно ли сделать это на PHP?

Comment: Запросто. Если введён юзер-пароль - формируешь уникальную случайную ссыль на файл (с ограниченными временем жизни и адресом доступа) и показываешь юзеру, пусть качает. А кто не ввёл - у того ссылки нет или адрес не тот...

Comment: @Akina Ну я не понял как это сделать, так что покажи как если можешь пожалуйста.

Comment: Не могу - я в PHP вообще ноль. Я только знаю, как это выглядит снаружи.

Comment: @Akina ясно, ок

Answer (score 2):

Как простой вариант можно не генерировать временную ссылку, а использовать сессию. 
Для проверки логина и пароля лучше все-таки сделать простую форму.
Вот код с пояснениями. У вас может быть своя структура файлов и организации кода. Даю просто идею. 
В файле index.php:

```
<?php session_start(); ?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
</head>
<body>

    <?php 
        // объявляем флаговую переменную для дальнейших проверок
        $isLoged = false;

        // проверяем пытался ли пользователь ввести логин и пароль
        if(isset($_POST['send'])){

            // фильтруем введенные пользователем данные
            $login = htmlspecialchars(trim($_POST['login']));
            $password = htmlspecialchars($_POST['password']);

            // проверяем введенный пользователем логин и пароль
            // здесь нужно написать настоящую проверку логина и пароля пользователя
            if($login === 'admin' && $password === 'qwerty') {
                // если проверка прошла, переводим флаговую переменную в true 
                // и записываем в сессию что-нибудь такое
                $isLoged = true;
                $_SESSION['user'] = 'isLoged';
            }
        }
    ?>

    <!-- если пользователь не прошел авторизацию выводим форму -->
    <?php if(!$isLoged): ?>
        <p>Для скачивания файла введите логин и пароль</p>
        <form method="post">
            <p>
                <b>Login:</b>
                <input type="text" name="login" value="<?php echo $login; ?>">
            </p>
            <p>
                <b>Password:</b>
                <input type="password" name="password">
            </p>
            <?php if(isset($_POST['send'])) : ?>
                <p><b>Неверный логин или пароль!</b></p>
            <?php endif; ?>    
            <input type="submit" name="send">
        </form>
    <?php endif; ?>

    <!-- если пользователь прошел авторизацию, то форма авторизации не выведетя, т.к. $isLoged === true 
         и показываем ссылку для скачивания -->
    <?php if($isLoged): ?>
        <p><a href="./download.php">Скачать</a></p>
    <?php endif; ?>


</body>
</html>
```

Файл download.php:

```
<?php
// запускаем сессию
session_start();
// проверяем авториован ли пользователь
if($_SESSION['user'] === 'isLoged') {
    // если авторизован, отдаем требуемый файл. Я просто вывел картинку с котиком
    // вы можете использовать имеющийся уже у вас код
    $image = file_get_contents('http://magspace.ru/uploads/2009/05/16/09-085832832-lg.jpg');
    header("Content-type: image/jpeg");
    echo $image;
    // удаляем из сессии данные об авторизации
    unset($_SESSION['user']);
} else {
    // если на эту страницу попал неавторизованный польхователь, т.е. данные в сессии отсутсвуют
    // генерируем ошибку 404 (как вариант).
    // тут может быть другая логика 
    header($_SERVER['SERVER_PROTOCOL'] . " 404 Not Found");
}
```

---

Для проверки логина и пароля можно написать простую функцию. В случае соответствия логина и пароля она вернет true, иначе false:

```
function checkUser($login, $password)
{
     $mysqli = mysqli_connect('127.0.0.1', 'root', '', 'php');
     $res = mysqli_query($mysqli, "SELECT id FROM users WHERE login= '$login' AND password = '$password' LIMIT 1");
     if( mysqli_num_rows($res) > 0) return true;
     return false;
}
```

И вызывать ее в нужном месте кода:

```
if(checkUser($login, $password)) {
  $isLoged = true;
  $_SESSION['user'] = 'isLoged';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Моё решение:

```php
<?php
$mysqli = mysqli_connect("server", "user", "pass", "db");
$res = mysqli_query($mysqli, "SELECT password FROM user WHERE login = '" . $_GET["login"] . "'");
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res);
if (is_array($row)) {
    foreach ($row as $r) {
        if ($r == $_GET["password"]) {
            header("Content-Description: File Transfer");
            header("Content-Type: application/zip");
            header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=".basename("files/test.zip"));
            header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
        }
    }
} else {
    if ($row == $_GET["password"]) {
        header("Content-Description: File Transfer");
        header("Content-Type: application/zip");
        header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=".basename("files/test.zip"));
        header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: А если передать в `$_GET["login"]` что-то типа `' OR 1 = 1 --`?

Comment: Ваше решение не безопасное. Нужно всегда проверять данные из $_GET. И способ проверки соответствия логина и пароля тоже не безопасны. Для проверки данных из get есть разные варианты, например https://www.php.net/manual/ru/mysqli.real-escape-string.php ($login = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_GET["login"]);).  Можно использовать ф-ции фильтрации данных https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.filter-input.php. Пароль тоже проверяем. А правильность логина и пароля лучше так: "SELECT id FROM users WHERE login= '$login' AND password = '$password' LIMIT 1"; Если mysqli_num_rows($res) > 0, разр.скачать

Comment: @МаксМаксимус А при каких условиях можно будет сделать вход небезопасным способом?

Comment: вот вам написал такой пример пользователь u_mulder:  "А если передать в $_GET["login"] что-то типа ' OR 1 = 1 -" . 1=1 будет всегда true и при любом введенном логине из вашей базы вернется нужный для входа пароль

Comment: WHERE login = '" . $_GET["login"] . "' вот кусок проверки пароля. WHERE login = '' OR 1 = 1' это что то сделает? Условие в кавычках будет проигнорировано.

Comment: Если в поисковую стоку браузера ввести https://my.website/download.php?login=' OR 1 = 1 -- ;  то sql запрос получится следующий: SELECT password FROM users WHERE login = '' OR 1 = 1 -- ;'  Т.е. условие будет выполнятся всегда (login равен пустой строке либо true). В итоге злоумышленнику не нужно знать логины пользователей. Такой sql запрос вернет пароль первого пользователя из вашей БД. А символы -- нужны чтоб интерпритировать весь дальнейший код sql как комментарии

Comment: @МаксМаксимус ну тогда вселенная схлопнится от такого запроса, ведь он будет некорректен